# Render items | React Native

Tags: react-native

Hi guys I have such a question.

I have a token stored in AsyncStorage. How do I do if `token = = = null` I loaded Button 1 on the page, and if something is loaded in token Button 2 ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do conditional rendering is by making use of states. 
First, create a state variable which will hold your condition with or without initial value based on what your logic is.

```
this.state = { conditionalVariable : false }
```

Second, create a variable that will hold your JSX to be rendered, inside the render method.
`

```
render() {
...
let conditionalContent = null;
...
}
```

Third, as soon as your token is available in your async storage, update/set your state.

```
this.setState({ conditionalVariable : token })
```

Before you return, write your logic based on what tags to return when. 
`

```
if (conditionalVariable == token1)
    conditionalContent = <Button1 />;
 else if (conditionalVariable == token2)
    conditionalContent = <Button2 />;
 else
    conditionalContent = ''; // dont display
```

Finally, inside your return, use your variable within {}.

```
<View>{conditionalContent}</View>
```

This way whenever your state is updated, your views will re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Question could be more clear, but there are so many ways get different outcomes. Here is just one random basic way.

```
<div>
    {token === null
        ? <Button1 />
        : <Button2 />
    }
</div>
```

You could also just change the properties based on the value or do different returns inside a render or other function...

https://reactpatterns.com/#conditional-rendering

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `token` is in the state, you could do following conditional (ternary):

```
<View>
  {!this.state.token ? <Button1 /> : <Button2 />}
</View>
```